# node.js saving form data using mongoose/mongodb/express has errors and wont work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am using express and mongoose to save my form data to my mongodb database but the operation won't work as it gives me an error that my model is not registered. my code:

index.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Admin-Page</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>admin-dashboard-interest</h1>
<form method="post" action="">
    <label for="select1">min select:</label>
    <select name="interest_active_user_min" id="select1">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>

    <label for="select2">max select:</label>
    <select name="interest_active_user_max" id="select2">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

schema.js

```
var InterestSchema = new Schema({
    settings: {
        admin_settings: {
            interest_settings: {
                interest_pending_user_settings: {
                        type: Number,
                        max: 100,
                        default: 0
                },

                interest_pending_user_value: {
                    type:[String]
                },

                interest_active_user:{
                    type:Number,
                    max:1000,
                    default:0
                },

                interest_active_user_max: {
                    type: Number,
                    max:1000,
                    default:100
                },

                interest_active_user_min: {
                    type: Number,
                    max:1000,
                    default: 5
                },

                active_interest: [{
                    name: {
                        type:[String],
                        unique:true
                    },
                    creator: {
                        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                        ref: 'User'
                    },
                    timestamp: {
                        type:Date,
                        default: Date.now
                    }
                }],

                pending_interest: [{
                    name: {
                        type:[String],
                        unique:true
                    },
                    creator: {
                        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                        ref: 'User'
                    },
                    timestamp: {
                        type:Date,
                        default: Date.now
                    }
                }],

                declined_interest: [{
                    name: {
                        type:[String],
                        unique:true
                    },
                    creator: {
                        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                        ref: 'User'
                    },
                    timestamp: {
                        type:Date,
                        default:Date.now
                    }
                }],

                removed_interest: [{
                    name: {
                        type:[String],
                        unique:true
                    },
                    creator: {
                        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                        ref: 'User'
                    },
                    timestamp: {
                        type:Date,
                        default: Date.now
                    }

                }]

            }
        }
    }
});
   var Int = mongoose.model('Interest', InterestSchema);
```

server.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

var morgan = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var uri = 'mongodb://localhost/interest';
var db = require('mongoose').connect(uri);

app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.listen(port);

console.log('shit happens on port ' + port);

app.get('/', function(req,res){
   res.render('index.ejs');
});



app.post('/', function(req,res){
var content = new Int(req.body.content);
    content.save(function(err){
        if(err){
            return handleError(err);
        } else {
            console.log('your form has been saved');
        }
    })
});


require('./models/schema.js');
```

I get an error "Int is not defined" which is the variable I used to register my mongoose model. I also required the mongoose file in my server.js so I don't see where I went wrong.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers.

Comment: Also, please do not use a snippet, unless the code can actually run in the browser.

Comment: You have neither exported your Int model from schema.js nor imported it in your server.js. The Int variable wont be available in your server.js unless you import it using require.

Comment: I did require('./models/schema.js') wouldn't this be suffice? what else steps must I take?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace in schema.js

```
var Int = mongoose.model('Int', InterestSchema);
```

and in server.js add

```
var Int = mongoose.model('Int');
```

It will work now.

ADD `var mongoose = require('mongoose');` IN `schema.js`

And the schemas should match.

Comment: hi, the schema is being saved to my database but the fields are not being populated?

Comment: Did you follow the above instructions?
It maybe because you are using `var content = new Int(req.body.content);`, your `content` should be of exact same schema as it is written in your model. So as your request body is not matching the schema, it is not being saved.

Comment: Yes, I followed the above instructions. What do you mean my "content" should be the exact same? under which part? I added content as I thought i had to specify form submission.

Comment: would it be any different if I just used req.body? instead of req.body.content

Comment: Actually what i am trying to say is, if your schema is `{a : String, b : Number} ` then `data` in  `var content = new Int(data); content.save(function(err){});` should also be exactly `{a : String, b : Number}`.

Comment: AND YOU HAVE NOT ADDED `var mongoose = require('mongoose');` IN `schema.js`. Maybe this was the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79412/discussion-between-lindan-chongwei-and-megamind).

Answer (score 0):

In your schema.js change last line to

```
exports.Int = mongoose.model('Interest', InterestSchema);
```

and in server.js(remove your last line)

```
var Int = require('./schema);
```

Answer (score 0):

action in html form is empty add action="/"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).